# remove entire rows when data is above 4 stdev

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I need to clean removing the rows that contain values that are above 4 stdev. I need to delete rows where one or more of the columns (2:18) value is above 4 stdev. How to best do this?

```
data.frame':    154940 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ msec: int  0 170 340 500 670 840 1010 1180 1340 1510 ...
 $ a412: num  0.0607 0.0584 0.0644 0.0607 0.0577 ...
 $ a440: num  0.0697 0.0649 0.0706 0.0706 0.0649 ...
 $ a488: num  0.0663 0.0633 0.0653 0.0673 0.0653 ...
 $ a510: num  0.466 0.459 0.44 0.462 0.445 ...
 $ a532: num  0.453 0.444 0.45 0.454 0.444 ...
 $ a555: num  0.428 0.424 0.436 0.426 0.428 ...
 $ a650: num  0.0839 0.0839 0.0839 0.0891 0.0865 ...
 $ a676: num  0.0963 0.0954 0.0963 0.1 0.0991 ...
 $ a715: num  0.0899 0.0912 0.0893 0.0887 0.0887 ...
 $ c412: num  0.343 0.337 0.342 0.346 0.344 ...
 $ c440: num  0.341 0.343 0.344 0.353 0.348 ...
 $ c488: num  0.33 0.335 0.337 0.345 0.34 ...
 $ c510: num  0.081 0.0802 0.0794 0.0794 0.081 ...
 $ c532: num  0.0594 0.0606 0.0582 0.057 0.0594 ...
 $ c555: num  0.067 0.0633 0.0615 0.0633 0.0689 ...
 $ c650: num  0.562 0.56 0.565 0.571 0.556 ...
 $ c676: num  0.549 0.552 0.551 0.55 0.537 ...
 $ c715: num  0.487 0.481 0.481 0.489 0.473 ...
```

Comment: What's the output of `dput` function?

Comment: @flojos Just to add AvinashRaj's comment, including a few lines of your data using `dput` would be useful.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show a test case of how to calculate the cut-off value?

Comment: This problem was my "inspiration" for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428748/delete-rows-in-r-if-a-cell-contains-a-value-larger-than-x), as I couldn't find a solution for this on SOF

Comment: stdev relative to what? Entire dataframe? Columns?

Comment: Hi everyone,thank you for responding so quickly. here is a link to the file created using dput [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9f1ujrz4en9138/foo?dl=0) .

Comment: The stdev should be calculated for each column individually. and the first column can be ignored as it correspond to the time of the measurements. I calculated 4stdev as follows but not sure whether that be any good. sd<-SD(acorr[2:19], na.rm = TRUE)
sd4<- 4 * sd