# R apply to subset dataframe

Tags: dataframe, subset, apply

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and I need to subset the dataframe so that each column has values more than 5. 
What I do is:

```
subset_df<-df[df$col1>5 & df$col2>5 & df$col3>5,]
```

What is a more general solution for dataframe with n columns, specifically with apply loop?

What I tried is

```
apply(df,function(x) x[x>5])
```

but it returns list instead of dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that each column will potentially have different lengths. A `list` is the most appropriate data type for what you want. You can keep your data as a data frame if you convert all `values < 5` to `NA`. You can do this with `df[df<5] <- NA`

Comment: @ChiPak in my case the dataframe will always have columns of the same lenghts.

Comment: Your input will have columns of the same length but can you guarantee that your output will?

Comment: @ChiPak sorry, now I see your point. So at every iteration it should remove the whole row somehow. What I can try is first your solution and then df[complete.cases(df), ]

Comment: `complete.cases` will remove the whole row even if one column contains a `NA`. Not sure that's what you want either...

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need, thanks. But still wondering it ti is possible to do with loops.

Comment: You should make this a separate post...

Comment: A very elegeant solution is here, although again without loops
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428748/delete-rows-in-r-if-a-cell-contains-a-value-larger-than-x